# Same parameter got passed into HTML but not button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to pass a parameter in angularjs. Please note the {{dish.id}} appear twice below, one was correctly passed, the other failed.

the html template is

```
<ion-popover-view>
  <ion-content>
  <button class="button button-full button-light" ng-click="addFavorite({{dish.id}})">
        Add to favorites: dish {{dish.id}} 
  </button> 

  <button class="button button-full button-light" ng-click="addComment()">Add comment</button>    
  </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

the function in the controller is

```
    $scope.addFavorite = function (index) {
    console.log("added from DishDetail: index is " + index);
    favoriteFactory.addToFavorites(index);
    console.log("finished");
    }
```

However, the weird thing is for the two {{dish.id}} in the view, the one in html was correctly displayed while the one to pass into the fucntion is "undefined"

[image]

Could someone kindly help me on resolving this? Kinda be stuck here for a few days and couldnt figure out myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer from my classmates, I shouldn't use handlebars when passing arguments to a javascript methods (╯‵□′)╯︵┻━┻

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of interpolation in ng- prefixed html attributes, those are handling by $scope.$apply() method

```
<button class="button button-full button-light" ng-click="addFavorite(dish.id)">
```